# An alternative more formal way to say: "I'll free up time to do something"

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, phrase-requests

I occasionally am answering emails where employers ask me whether I am interested in applying for a position.

I would like to reply something along the lines: That I am interested and I should soon "carve out" the time to fill out an application.

But this form feels too casual to me as if I am not taking the proposal seriously or too busy to consider it...

So I came up with an alternative form: ***"I should get around to file the online application soon"***  - Is it correct and formal enough expression to be used in an email to a potential employer?

I am not native English speaker and am not sure this is an appropriate answer in this situation. Nevertheless, it sounds that this answer conveys what I want to say in a formal enough way and does not stress too much that I am "too busy" to deal with the application.

Thanks!

Comment: No!! “carve out” sounds ***much*** more purposeful than “get around to it”.  If you want to convey a nonchalant “I don’t really care” attitude then use “get around to it”

Answer (score 1):

"I will make it a priority"

... is more formal than "I'll get around to it"

... but without an indication of 'when' you might still sound evasive.

"I will make it a priority to get it done before the end of the week" is more what people would hope to hear.  Of course, that also means that they are expecting you get it done by then.

Comment: Thanks! though, indeed, I was looking for an answer where I do not specify a date to avoid missing it.

Comment: @them-  if you are unwilling to commit to a date then you really don’t care enough about the job. In which case why even bother replying at all?

Comment: The comment of @Jim is absolutely right.  If you can't make a commitment to fill out an application form by a day that is acceptable to the person offering the job, why should he be interested in hiring you?

Comment: Jim is right.

The most obvious more formal way to say 'I'll free up time…' is simply 'I'll make time…' but neither is in any way appropriate here.

You need 'I'll do it by/on Tuesday' or 'I'll do it right away' and in either case, you need to stick to it.